# Mongo as a service on Non Mongo Hosting Servers

Tags: mongodb, mean-stack

I am building a app using Mean Stack (Mongo + Express + Backbone + Node) approach. I am already having a Web hosting plan but it does not provides Mongo as database. I thought of deploying my app on that hosting server and place my mongo db on one of the Mongo as service websites. Is this possible.I don't want to buy a new Hosting Plan for this alone.

Comment: Perhaps you should switch to a VPS, they are really cheap and you can do what you want. But it should be possible. You just need to define your app to connect to the external server. But take care of encryption and security, when using different services!

Comment: Should be possible as long as your hosting server allows connections on the port the mongodb server (on the mongo as a service platform) exposes.

Comment: ok, i will check with my hosting plan provider for the port.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout mongolabs or monhohq.
They even have free tier hosting plans.
BTW checkout mean.io it brings a lot of the mean related integrations out of the box.